# Using DataGrip for Export/Import SQLLite3 -> Postgres 14

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, datagrip

After a number of DB migration tools failed for me (pgloader, among others) to smoothly migrate my sqlite DB to Postgres, I'm using DataGrip to copy table by table, using the Export feature to generate SQL INSERT statements, then running them in a console. I don't have toooo many tables, so this is OK. The only issue is boolean fields, with SQLlite encodes as `0` and `1`, but Postgres wants `false` and `true`. What's the best way to alter either the export or import process to fix these boolean values?

[image: Source table]

Comment: BTW you don't need to:
1. Export tables one by one
2. Use generate INSERT statements

Instead, use 'Copy multiple objects' feature: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/whatsnew/2022-1/#importexport

Answer (score 0):

Option to select boolean values representation in Export feature is not yet implemented in DataGrip.

Please see and follow [DBE-11944](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-11944).